# In the aftermath of a revolution, what would be the immediate concerns?

Tags: politics, government, cities

For seven hundred years, a city (and the surrounding lands) was ruled by oppressive kings and the high nobles (who are of elvish descent and consider themselves above the other people). A group of rebels finally rose up and overthrew the king and the nobles.

The story starts up in the days immediately following the revolution, with the leader of the revolution as the main character. He never expected to live through the uprising, and is at a loss for what to do to create a stable democracy, mainly in the city but possibly in the surrounding lands as well. There are several of groups fighting for power at this point: the City Watch, the rebels, several criminal groups, the displaced nobles, various religious groups, and the guilds (especially the Merchants' Guild).

- At this point, what would be the main concerns of the rebels and society at large?
- How might they go about establishing a stable democratic government?

Comment: Welcome to WB:SE.  We appreciate your participation, but you've asked a question that is too broad and primarily opinion-based, which will get your question put on hold.  Please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3624/29) to learn more about how to ask a great question.  Specifically, without much more information about the rules of your world and status of your population/government/infrastructure/military/etc./etc., this question cannot be answered definitively.  We hope you edit your question to improve our chances of answering it.  Thanks!

Comment: You can mine this question for a lot of the material you want...  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/96724/rebuilding-a-medieval-type-land-after-a-war  Disclaimer, I have my own answer in there, which is why I thought of that question when I saw yours.

Comment: The question is, as @JBH said, kind of broad. It is missing a lot of information. How big is the place? Do the surrounding lands extend from the capital city at around 1 day's march or 3? Are the displaced nobles based in the city, the outskirts area or those state capitals? What is the level on the tech tree(sure kings and guilds and elves(ish) are largely medieval stuff but the can occur anytime(think UK, London, The City Of London and genetic engineering)? Basically you would do with a little **background and setup**.

Comment: Plus, then is the distance from the city to the remote border village or the local trade and power center(like a state capital)?

Comment: He cannot go wrong with establishing a [Committe of Public Safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Committee_of_Public_Safety) and behead all the nobles he can catch, their friends, the friends of their friends, all the people who had ever displeased him, and their friends. Then he will be beheaded too, and eventually a strong autocratic ruler will emerge, who will proceed to establish a great empire, which will fall, and after about 150 years the [Fifth Republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Fifth_Republic) will have a stable democratic government.

Comment: @AlexP c'mon, nobody would believe that.  He'd be better off having his rebels execute the nobles as per normal, but then immediately set up a tightly planned economy and bureaucratic state and engage in ruthless social engineering.  Use semi-engineered famines to dispose of disliked factions, and engage in mass population movements and relentless internal propaganda.  Keep this up for 80 years or so, then collapse due to competition from freer economies.  Afterward, try to rebuild a civil society.  It'll be touch and go for a while, but time will tell.

Comment: AlexP, akaioi, I think both of you are eating some shrooms! Obviously, what you're really going to want to do is use your outsider status to gain leadership of the new country. Give grand speeches advocating passionately for reconciliation between the factions. Meet with the nobility, assure them that their rights & prerogs will remain intact; form elections, allowing your cronies to intimidate smaller factions; win, rename the country, systematically remove old royal symbols. Begin a program of "buying" noble lands. When that fails, seize said assets, blame other factions & seize all control.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rebuilding a Medieval-type Land after a war](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/96724/rebuilding-a-medieval-type-land-after-a-war)

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Law and Order

Revolutions are a dirty business, especially the bloody ones. They tend to attract all kinds of people from idealists to criminals. Criminals might be a valuable asset during the revolutionary struggle (they know how to get things done), but any reasonable ruler will want to lock them up once the new power is established.

It seems that your revolution was bloody one and involved a civil war. So it is safe to assume that a lot of property is destroyed and old laws and rules no longer apply. You will see a steep rise in petty crimes (stealing food, supplies, brawls, etc.). It would be a good idea to deal with them swiftly.

So, I would propose organising some kind of police force that will restore law and order in the area. Maybe you can start with militia and a bit later, when you have money/goods, hire professionals. This is, probably, the most important step if you want to achieve stability. People must believe in their state and its ability to protect them.

### 2. Feed the People

Revolutions often result in a big chunk of a population not having means for survival. As a benevolent ruler, you have to take care of those people. (It also makes political sense to do so, as hungry people are potential rebels.) You might have to nationalise some food reserves, organise soup kitchens, and start growing food on public lands to feed your people.

You can also expect an increase in the number of orphans. Depending on your society, it might be a state's responsibility to provide for them while they are young. Alternatively, the state might give jobs or issue subsidies to caretakers.

### 3. Rebuilding and Restoring Normal Life

Rebuilding should be started immediately. The priorities will depend on a society. However, it will make a leader more popular if they focus on immediate population needs, for example, shelters and water sources.

As much as possible should be done to restore at least visibility of normalcy. Citizens should be allowed to resume their lives ASAP. They should be more concerned with today's menu choices than with a government's course of action. Encourage people to return to their homes or to settle down. Give them the stability they crave after all the recent changes. People will more likely place their trust in a leader that is capable of achieving at least some stability.

### 4. Democracy?

Perhaps, it would not be the wisest choice to try democracy right after the revolution. Democracy demands an existence of civil society. I would doubt that after seven centuries of oppressive monarchy people will be ready to make informed political choices. They will be a way too easy prey for populists and demagogues.

A provisional government might be a better choice. This government will be tasked with rebuilding the country and establishing legal and social frameworks for a future democracy. If they are lucky, they might even initiate a peaceful transfer of power once everything is in place. But historically it took centuries to go from absolute monarchies to democracies. So, I would not be too optimistic.

Answer (score 2):

By far the #1 concern after a revolution is *radicalization*, followed by *overthrow* of the original moderate revolutionary regime by a more radical group.

After the revolution, the alliances that created the popular revolt fall apart, and fringe movements (that were often previously suppressed) see their opportunity.

The fringe (radical) movements subvert civil society and institutions and attack the credibility of more popular centrist groups using propaganda, strikes, terrorism, etc. Fear, uncertainty, and violence are common radical tools. Upon attaining power, most radical groups promptly suppress competing groups.

Examples:

- Jacobins and the Reign of Terror (1793) after the French Revolution (1789-1792)
- Chinese Civil War (1916-1949) after the Xinhai Revolution (1911)
- the Bolshevik Revolution (Oct 1917) after the February Revolution (Feb 1917) during the Russian Revolution of the 1917
- Islamization (Apr 1979) of the Iranian Revolution (1978-1979)

Answer (score 1):

So, everyone unites against a common enemy (in your case the current government). When this enemy is defeated, everyone suddenly remembers the motivations that brought them there.

That's *kiiinda* the problem when a bunch of guys who are ready to kill people for their political views realize they all have different political views.

- Authoritatian Political Party #1: kill everyone from Authoritatian Political Party #2
- Authoritatian Political Party #2: kill everyone from Authoritatian Political Party #1
- Leaders of the three non-dominant religions (who all hate each other btw): turning the state into a theocracy based on their own religion and converting everyone else.
- The Mafia: power, money, bribes.
- Politicians: see "Mafia".
- Others: land, money, and all the stuff you promised to give them to enlist their help.
- Guilds: less taxes, more money (and please kill off the competition)
- ...and your hero: idealism, desire for democracy.

And let's not forget...

- Foreign countries: notice a power vacuum and invade yours.
- International arms manufacturers: keep it going, it sells guns!
- USA: finance one side to keep it going since it annoys the Russians
- Russians: same, with the other side
- Etcetera

So, naturally the cast will split into subgroups which will keep murdering each other until a clear leader emerges (AlexP and akaioi provide nice examples in the comments...) Y'know, the usual, let's send leninists to the gulag, then the trotskists, then... etc.

> At this point, what would be the main concerns of the rebels and society at large?

Society at large would mostly be concerned with having enough to eat, and not getting killed. If there is no more authority, is there still any police or law enforcement? Do you have bands of armed rebels, criminals, or social justice warriors roaming the streets and seizing the stash of food you keep for the winter "for the greater good" ?...

Many people will think "damn, it was so much better before!" (but will not voice their opinion for fear of losing their head).

> How might they go about establishing a stable democratic government?

See: Chile. Make communist revolution. Establish "Popular Democratic Republic Of...", complete with famine, shortage of everything, and armed gangs of militia terrorizing the populations. Wait until a military dictator takes power and murders the previous regime while the people cheer. Then wait until the new dictator dies of old age and decides to get democratic. Can take a while if his name starts with "Kim" though.