# Is the idea of one big world empire a realistic one?

Tags: government

There have been many big empires but no real world empires. Would it be possible for a great power to take control of most of the world and create a single nation?

Do you think it would function properly and would the different continents form there own nations over time?

Or is it just an impossible task to create and control one big nation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the necessary conditions for a worldwide government?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/96/what-are-the-necessary-conditions-for-a-worldwide-government)

Comment: Possible VTC - Opinion-based?

Comment: @Raisus If you feel the question is a poor fit for the site for some reason, then just flag it as such. There is no need to call it out in the comments; an off-topic flag by itself carries very little weight, but will be pointed out to users looking at the question in the review queue. (Flagging as spam or offensive is a different matter.)

Comment: Stable non-dictatorial Global Government is only possible if there is more than one globe, because there will be at least 2 viable ideas on how to do everything and eventually that stress will break it apart into 2 pieces at minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's by no means *impossible*, but don't expect absolute control

[image: british empire, 1921]

This is a picture of the British Empire, at its peak in 1921. At this point they controlled around one fifth of the total land area on Earth.

As you can see,  the territories are spread far and wide, and so they didn't really have that much control. Eventually, control became influence.

However, it gets better

[image: Mongol Empire]

*(Original source: https://www.essential-humanities.net/img/history/his46.jpg)*

Behold the great Mongol Empire. At its greatest the Khans controlled most of central asia, and were only stopped by the Romans. They also had influence over India, but that's not shown on this map. Other than the Roman Empire, Mongolia controlled the entirety of (what was considered) the civilised world.

So it's not too unreasonable for an empire spanning the world, but it will split from internal pressures eventually, as at least someone is going to disagree.

Comment: ...stopped by the ROMANS?  Whom are you referring to?  Last I recall it was the establishment of the Mamluks which pushed the Mongols out of the Middle East, and incidentally proved effective against Crusaders too.  The only "Romans" of this era are the Byzantines?  Holy Romans?  Never heard them referred to as such.

Comment: @inappropriateCode The Byzantine had been conquered by the mongols when they entered Europe . The Holy Roman Empire was in France , Germany , Italy , & Spain. The Mongols never so much as Breathed on them. Giacomo just has his history wrong.

Comment: @TheoclesofSaturn Yeah, I was very confused.  Thought: but surely, the Roman empire proper is long gone, the east is dying, the HRE doesn't know about the Mongol.  What's left?!